# omp barriers are blocking

Tags: openmp, barrier

I have a code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

static void func()
{
    char t[30];
    sprintf(t,"%d %d\n",omp_get_num_threads(),omp_get_thread_num());
    write(1,t,strlen(t));
    write(1,"checkpoint 1\n",13);
    #pragma omp barrier 
    write(1,"checkpoint 2\n",13);
    #pragma omp barrier
    write(1,"checkpoint 3\n",13);
    #pragma omp barrier
    write(1,"checkpoint 4\n",13);
}

int main()
{
    int i;
#pragma omp parallel for
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
       func();
    }
}
```

and the output:

```
8 1
8 0
checkpoint 1
checkpoint 1
checkpoint 2
checkpoint 2
[here my program blocks].
```

if I change 2 in for to 8, it works. but I want to have 2 in my for loop.

how to make my code working without using omp_set_num_threads(2) before the loop? (also it works when I put this)

Comment: OpenMP barriers are global among the threads in the team. You cannot have just two out of N threads synchronise on a barrier. That's why it works when you explicitly set the number of threads to two.

Answer (score 3):

Barriers are used to synchronize **all** threads in the team. All arriving threads will be blocked until all threads have reached the barrier. Then and only then may they all continue.

As a consequence of this, in order for your program to terminate, all threads have to reach the same number of barriers during their life. If one thread has more barriers than the others, that thread can never pass its extra barrier because it will wait for the other threads - which will never get there because they don't have that extra barrier.

You have a barrier in the function `func`, which is executed once per iteration of your parallel loop. Since it's up to OpenMP to assign those iterations to threads, not all of them may receive the same number of iterations (in your case they do receive the same number for a thread count of 2 - one iteration for every thread, that's why your program terminates then). That unequal number of barriers blocks your program.

Make sure to place barriers only in places where you know that all threads will execute it equally often.

Comment: I don't think this answer correctly explains the behavior described in the question. The reasons given in this answer would explain why a program may block after printing `checkpoint 1` two times. But in this case, the program prints `checkpoint 1` two times, then prints `checkpoint 2` two times, and then blocks. That `checkpoint 2` is printed must mean that all threads have reached and passed the first barrier. It looks like the threads then block at the second barrrier. Strange.

Comment: P.S.: I guess I should add that your answer is a good explanation of barriers and problems similar to the one described in the question. Upvote.

Comment: @jcsahnwaldt Wow, you are right, I didn't pay attention to that fact. Anyway, I ran the code again and it blocked at the *first* barrier. I couldn't get it to reach the second one, no matter how hard I twisted the parameters and the timing. And that's really the only thing that *can* happen given the code above. So I guess there was just a mismatch between the code version posted and the output version. It happens a lot when people try to get things to work and keep modifying the code. But thanks for pointing it out!